# unexpected unicode values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find why this is happening. Can i get a justification ?

using pandas in python, if I write in the console:

```
pd.io.json.read_json('{"rCF":{"values":0.05}}')
```

I got printed a dataframe that looks like this

```
        rCF
values  0.05
```

This if fine.

But if I write in the console:

```
pd.io.json.read_json('[{"rCF":{"values":0.05}}]')
```

I got printed a dataframe that looks like this

```
     rCF
0    {u'values': 0.05}
```

in particular, why the key is u'values' and not just 'values'

Answer (score 2):

`json` always decodes to Unicode:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"a":"b"}')
{u'a': u'b'}
```

It's just that in your former case a `print` or the equivalent somewhere inside `pandas` is hiding this, as would, e.g:

```
>>> x = _
>>> for k in x: print k
... 
a
```

after the above snippet; but when you `print` (or the like) a **container**, you get to see the more precise `repr` of the container's items.