# UnicodeDecodeError on json.loads after json.dump with ensure_ascii=False in python 2.x

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-unicode

I dump dict object using `json.dump`. To avoid `UnicodeDecodeError`, I set `ensure_ascii=False` following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872773/unicodedecodeerror-while-using-json-dumps).

```
with open(my_file_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False))
```

The dump file has been successfully created, but when loading the dumped file UnicodeDecodeError happens:

```
with open(my_file_path, "r") as f:
    return json.loads(f.read())
```

How to avoid `UnicodeDecodeError` on loading the dump file?

#### Error message and stacktrace

The Error message is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte` and stacktrace is:

```
/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336     if (cls is None and encoding is None and object_hook is None and
    337             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
--> 338             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    339         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    340     if cls is None:

/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    364         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    365         end = _w(s, end).end()
--> 366         if end != len(s):
    367             raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
    368         return obj

/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    380             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    381         except StopIteration:
--> 382             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    383         return obj, end

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Python 2.x. Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Comment: what happens if you `ensure_ascii=True`?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso `json.dump(my_dict, ensure_ascii=True)` raises `
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: What happens if you `import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Unfortunately, `import sys reload(sys) sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` does not occur nothing to change both on `json.dump` and `json.loads`

Comment: Don't you use "Windows 1252" or "ISO-8859-1" characters in your dict object?  In those codes,  "0x93" is assigned to 'LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' character ,which is used in spanish.

Comment: @Fumu7 Yeah. might be true. Actually, my dict is very large and difficult to detect or replace illegal characters. Is there some way to ignore those illegal characters?

Comment: Does changing "w" to "wb" and "r" to "rb" help?

Answer (score 2):

In Python2, you could use `ensure_ascii=False` *and decode the result* before calling `json.loads`:

```
import json

my_dict = {b'\x93': [b'foo', b'\x93', {b'\x93': b'\x93'}]}

dumped = json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
print(repr(dumped))
# '{"\\u201c": ["foo", "\\u201c", {"\\u201c": "\\u201c"}]}'
result = json.loads(dumped.decode('cp1252'))
print(result)
# {u'\u201c': [u'foo', u'\u201c', {u'\u201c': u'\u201c'}]}
```

However, note that the `result` returned by `json.loads` contains `unicode`, not `str`s. So the `result` is not exactly the same as `my_dict`.

Note that `json.loads` [**always** decodes strings to unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27592690/190597), so if you are interested in faithfully recovering the dict using `json.dumps` and `json.loads`, then you need to start with a dict which contains only `unicode`, no `str`s.

Moreover, in Python3 `json.dumps` *requires* all dicts to have keys which are unicode strings. So the above solution does not work in Python3.

---

An alternative which will work in both Python2 and Python3 is to make sure you
pass `json.loads` a dict whose keys and values are `unicode` (or contain no
`str`s). For example, if you use `convert` (below) to recursively change the
keys and values to `unicode` before passing them to `json.loads`:

```
import json

def convert(obj, enc):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.decode(enc)
    if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return [convert(item, enc) for item in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {convert(key, enc) : convert(val, enc)
                for key, val in obj.items()}
    else: return obj

my_dict = {'\x93': ['foo', '\x93', {'\x93': '\x93'}]}
my_dict = convert(my_dict, 'cp1252')

dumped = json.dumps(my_dict)
print(repr(dumped))
# '{"\\u201c": ["foo", "\\u201c", {"\\u201c": "\\u201c"}]}'
result = json.loads(dumped)
print(result)
# {u'\u201c': [u'foo', u'\u201c', {u'\u201c': u'\u201c'}]}
assert result == my_dict
```

`convert` will decode all `str`s found in lists, tuples and dicts inside `my_dict`.

Above, I used `'cp1252'` as the encoding since (as [Fumu pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880789/unicodedecodeerror-on-json-loads-after-json-dump-with-ensure-ascii-false-in-pyth#comment59426084_35880789)) `'\x93'` decoded with `cp1252` is a `LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`:

```
In [18]: import unicodedata as UDAT

In [19]: UDAT.name('\x93'.decode('cp1252'))
Out[19]: 'LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK'
```

If you know the `str`s in `my_dict` have been encoded in some other encoding,
you should of course call `convert` using that encoding instead.

---

Even better, instead of using `convert`, take care to ensure all `str`s are decoded to `unicode` *as you are building* `my_dict`.